# Congruences and Exponents Problem 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

How would you show that $37 \times 2^{220} - 14 \times 5^{87} \times 7^{87}$ is divisible by $17$?

I tried finding the actual answer of the equation to show that it is divisible by $17$, but I think I need a more efficient and stronger proof. What could this proof be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$2^{4} \equiv -1 \mod 17$$

$$35 \equiv 1 \mod 17$$

Edit:

\begin{align}
37 \times 2^{220} - 14 \times 5^{87} \times 7 ^{87}
&\equiv (2 \times 17+3) \times(2^4)^{55}-(17-3) \times 35^{87}\mod 17 \\ &\equiv3 \times (-1)^{55} - (-3)\times 1^{87}\mod17 \\
&\equiv (-3)-(-3) \mod 17 \\
&\equiv 0 \mod 17
\end{align}

Comment: I agree, initially I thought of computing $220 \mod 16$

Comment: That's slick.  And $37\equiv -14\equiv 3$